# different line space for thesis

Tags: line-spacing

I am writing my thesis using KOMA-script in LyX. I have followed the guide from this link

http://fkurth.de/uwest/LyX/ThesisTemplate/Diss-Template.zip

However, I have a issue related to the line spacing. I would like to have a single space in front pages, biobliography, ... and double space in all the chapter 1,2,3. **How can we set a different line space in front pages and branch chapter?**

I have tried a few thing but not work, like setting up a text layout in the branch chapter in to double space.

The preamble in both main document and branch is

```
% print no date
\date{}

% increase link area for cross-references and autoname them
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\mbox{\autoref{#1}}}}
\newlength{\abc}
\settowidth{\abc}{\space}
\addto\extrasenglish{
 \renewcommand{\equationautorefname}{\hspace{-\abc}}
 \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Fig.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{Tab.\negthinspace}
}

% in case somebody want to have the label "equation"
%\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{equation~(\negthinspace\autoref{#1})}

% that links to image floats jumps to the beginning
% of the float and not to its caption
\usepackage[figure]{hypcap}

% the pages of the TOC is numbered roman
% and a pdf-bookmark for the TOC is added
\let\myTOC\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \frontmatter
  \pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{}
  \myTOC
  \mainmatter }

% make caption labels bold
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\setcapindent{1em}

% enable calculations
\usepackage{calc}

% fancy page header/footer settings
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
%\lhead[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\lfoot[\thepage]{}
\rfoot[]{\thepage}
\cfoot{}

% increase the bottom float placement fraction
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.5}

% avoid that floats are placed above its sections
\let\mySection\section\renewcommand{\section}{\suppressfloats[t]\mySection}

% widen the space for the nomenclature entry labels
\renewcommand{\nomlabelwidth}{2.5cm}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example is not complete since it is an excerpt of a LyX file. Most probably, the package `setspace` and the commands `singlespacing` before the frontmatter and `\doublespacing` after the frontmatter stuff will help

Comment: Thank you! You are right to make a \singlespacing before. Problem is solved